# Get a JavaScript variable from a remote page?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, screen-scraping

I am currently working on developing an API for a company. Specifically, here's my issue. They have JavaScript arrays on a webpage that their webmaster updates. I have to pull these arrays into either a simple JS script or PHP file and get the contents of these arrays, which I can then arrange according to the API's specifications and output it as JSON.

How do I pull a JavaScript variable in from a remote page in either PHP or jQuery/JS and make it usable for other applications?

No, I don't have access to the company's website. I have to work off of page scraping for this one.

Thank you!

Comment: You will need the web site to wrap it in JSONP to do it via Javascript. Otherwise you will have to parse this on a server (so PHP may work for you here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I where you, I’d use PHP to `file_get_contents` (or `CURL` depending on the server config) the page and then parse it based on whatever the markers are to find the value of the variable, assuming it’s written out to the page in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access private javascript variables remotely, due to [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). They would have to output the arrays in some kind of readable format that you could access using AJAX, probably as JSON.

Edit: As mentioned below, if the array is explicitly defined as text in a javascript file, you could grab the contents of that file using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP

Comment: He said using PHP (which runs on his server) is possible.

Comment: Only if the javascript file explicitly defines the full array in the code. He could then grab the file using cURL, but my guess is that if he needs to grab something like this, it's not being explicitly defined in text form. If it is, then yeah, cURL would work.